# Angular 2 Pipe - can't return value inside a promise

Tags: angular, promise, pipe

I'm trying to do a really simple translate pipe for angular2. But I might be wrong how to promise work. The idea is to get the language parameter from a async service which call a doc in PouchDB. 
Fyi, the data are organised like this:

```
{
title: {
   fr: "text in french",
   en : "text in english",
...
}
```

The return inside the promise doesn't work. The html template is empty. I don't get why.

```
@Pipe({name: 'translate'})

export class Translate {

  lang:any;

  constructor(private interfaceService: Interface){}

  transform(obj) {

    this.interfaceService.getParams().then((data) => {
      return obj[data.language]
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });

  }

}
```

If I put the return outside of the promise, it works:

```
@Pipe({name: 'translate'})

export class Translate {

  lang:any;

  constructor(private interfaceService: Interface){}

  transform(obj) {
   return obj.en

  }

}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must return the resulting promise from the function.

```
export class Translate {
  // ...
  transform(obj) {
    return this.interfaceService.getParams().then((data) => {
      return obj[data.language]
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      throw error; // or `return Promise.reject(error);`
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works but I stil have a problem. It returns an [object object] in the template ! I tried many things like using the pipe "json" and it showed after:`{"__zone_symbol__state":true,"__zone_symbol_value":"Text in english"}` I tried to return a simple string but it is the same result...

Comment: @katzu I think you need async pipes https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html#!#async-pipe

Comment: Yeap thanks a lot that was it, just use the async pipe

Comment: In my case it returns [object Promise]

Comment: @Donovant thats expected